# Pointing to particular location using Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

Below is my complete code of fragment which should display google map AND point to a particular location in the map.

```
package com.example.sample.karcha;

import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;


public class PurchasePlaceFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

    private static final String TAG = "LocatrFragment";
    private GoogleApiClient mClient;
    private GoogleMap mMap;


    private SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;
    private Location mCurrentLocation;

    public static  SupportMapFragment newInstance() {

        PurchasePlaceFragment fragment = new PurchasePlaceFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;
            updateUI();
        }
    });
}

private void updateUI() {

    if (mMap == null ) {
        return;
    }

    LatLng itemPoint = new LatLng(51.508530,-0.076132);
    LatLng myPoint = new LatLng(
            mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
    LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder()
            .include(itemPoint)
            .include(myPoint)
            .build();
    int margin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.map_inset_margin);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, margin);
    mMap.animateCamera(update);
}
}
```

Execution of this code only displays the map , but it does not point to a particular location.

My understanding is onMapReady() is not executing and therefore updateUI() is not  getting called.

Any idea where is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The call to **getMapAsysnc** doesn't seems to be done in the right manner.

Note: **onMapReady() gets called by calling getMapAsysnc() on MapFragment instance.**

Looking at your code what you have shared, it's directly calling getMapAsysnc()

Try changing it to

```
mMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;
            updateUI();
        }
    });
```

This should give you the desired result.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No value has been assigned to mMapFragment variable ,I think that is not the issue.

Comment: Here is the documentation stating the same what I posted. kindly check your code once again. This is clearly mentioned there "Call getMapAsync() on the fragment to register the callback."